# Getting the largest value in a table

Tags: lua, coronasdk, lua-table

How can I get the largest value in a table in Corona SDK/Lua?

For example, I have this table:

```
local table = {
   ["item1"] = 10,
   ["item2"] = 20,
   ["item3"] = 30,
   ["item4"] = 40,
   ["item5"] = 50
}
```

I have to get item5 and its value 50 as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
local max_val, key = -math.huge
for k, v in pairs(your_table) do
    if v > max_val then
        max_val, key = v, k
    end
end
print(key, max_val)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have non-numeric keys then sorting won't work and you will just need to walk the table manually keeping track of the max value and it associated key.