# Lua - Analysing values in a text file

Tags: lua

I’m writing power (watts) values to a text file in order to extract information I can use.

```
4.7
4.7
4.8
5.2
5.1
4.6
4.6
4.6
```

Currently I have the following code to give me the average, but I’d like to add to it so it tells me more such as, what was the highest value, the lowest value, the most frequent value, and if at all possible if there are any ‘0’ values recorded (* - if possible with that last one it would be good to ignore them..)

```
local ctr = 0
local sum = 0

for _ in io.lines"/www/EnergyPlug-b.txt" do
    ctr = ctr + 1
end
print(ctr)

for line in io.lines"/www/EnergyPlug-b.txt" do 
    sum = sum + line
end
print(sum)
average = sum / ctr
print(average)
```

I did explore creating a Lua table via `table.insert()` off of the first `io.lines` section, like the following, but I’m not sure how good it is?

```
local rows = {}
-- go over the file line by line
for line in io.lines("/www/EnergyPlug-b.txt") do
  -- if line matches ?.? then insert into table
  local value = line:match("%d%p%d") -- 1.5 
    --print(value) 
    table.insert(rows, value)
end

local arraymax = math.max(unpack(rows))
local arraymin = math.min(unpack(rows))

print (arraymax) -- ?.?
print (arraymin) -- ?.?
```

If the above is suitable, how best should I go about identifying the items/values i mentioned at the very start ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first snippet there is no reason to have a separate loop for ctr and sum. You can do it in one loop.

Your second snipped is ok. `unpack` is limited so this won't work for many thousand values.

You have to traverse the table anyway to get the other values so you can determin min and max in that loop too without that size limit.

`local value = line:match("%d%p%d")` if there are only those numbers in that file you can skip the pattern matching here.

The calculations are pretty straigt forward. I'm not sure what you're struggling with here.

```
local min = math.huge -- use a value that is definitely bigger than any value
local max = -math.huge -- use a value that is definitely smaller than any value
local counts = {} -- an emtpy table we'll use to count how often each value occurs
local numIngored = 0 -- how many 0 values have we ignored?
for line in io.lines(yourFileName) do
  -- convert string to a number
  local value = tonumber(line)
  -- if we take the value into account
  if value ~= 0.0 then
    -- update min and max values
    min = value < min and value or min
    max = value > max and value or max
    -- update counts
    counts[value] = counts[value] and counts[value] + 1 or 1
  else
    -- count ignored values
    numIgnored = numIgnored + 1
  end
end
```

I'll leave it up to you to get the most frequent values from `counts`

Comment: Thanks so much @piglet, ok, so i now have a min and a max, plus a table with a count of each recorded value. To find the most frequent one, I can do that via this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17461317/getting-the-largest-value-in-a-table

Comment: To avoid me doing another loop to find the average, is there a way to factor that calculation in as part of your min, max and count section ?

Comment: just calculate the sum and count while reading the file? that should be pretty obvious if you have spent more than a minute thinking about your problem. maybe think about hos you would solve this with pen and paper first

Comment: the linked post won't give you more than one value. what if there are multiple most frequent values?

Comment: Thanks @piglet, please believe me when I say,  I think about these for ages before posting them, sadly the logic just doesn’t come as easily to me as I’d like, and i often end up doing everything separately, rather than in one chunk;  but I’m getting better :-). Regarding that linked post, yep I saw that too,  and I’m exploring options..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @piglet and using other SO posts, here is what I ended up with..

```
local min = math.huge -- use a value that is definitely bigger than any value
local max = -math.huge -- use a value that is definitely smaller than any value
local ctr = 0
local valtotal = 0
local counts = {} -- an emtpy table we'll use to count how often each value occurs
local numIngored = 0 -- how many 0 values have we ignored?
for line in io.lines("/www/EnergyPlug-b.txt") do
  -- convert string to a number
  local value = tonumber(line)
  -- if we take the value into account
  if value ~= 0.0 then
    ctr = ctr + 1
    valtotal = valtotal + value
    -- update min and max values
    min = value < min and value or min
    max = value > max and value or max
    -- update counts
    counts[value] = counts[value] and counts[value] + 1 or 1
  else
    -- count ignored values
    numIgnored = numIgnored + 1
  end
end

print("----Table print out -----")

for k, v in pairs(counts) do
    print(k,v)
end

print("---------------------------")
print("Lowest value recorded = " ..min)
print("Highest value recorded = " ..max)
print("Average value recorded = " ..round2(valtotal / ctr, 1))
print("Number of values recorded = " ..ctr)
print("---------------------------")

local max_val, key1 = -math.huge
for k, v in pairs(counts) do
    if v > max_val then 
        max_val, key1 = v, k
    end
end

local min_val, key2 = math.huge 
for k1, v1 in pairs(counts) do
    if v1 < min_val or v1 == min_val then
        min_val, key2 = v1, k1
    end
end

local min_qty, max_qty = 0, 0
local min_str, max_str = "", ""
for k2, v2 in pairs(counts) do
    if v2 == min_val then
        min_qty = min_qty + 1
        min_str = min_str .. " " .. k2
    elseif v2 == max_val then
        max_qty = max_qty + 1
        max_str = max_str .. " " .. k2
    end
end

if min_qty == 1 then
    print("Least recorded value was = " ..key2.. " recorded "..min_val.." times")
else
    print("Least recorded values were = " ..min_str.. " each recorded "..min_val.." time")
end
if max_qty == 1 then
    print("Most recorded value was = " ..key1.. " recorded "..max_val.." times")
else
    print("Least recorded values were = " ..max_str.. " each recorded "..max_val.." time")
end
print("---------------------------")
```